# iOS - Getting desired shadow above UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I am trying to get my tab bar shadow to look like the one seen in this image:

[image]

What is the best way of doing this? I am using objective-c
Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can give shadow by using following code to any UI object

```
tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2
tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
```

Here i gave example for your tabControl object.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. If anyone wanted to know, to make it look like that image, I used a shadow radius of 8 and a shadow opacity of 0.3. Once again, thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. (iOS 13+) Has there been some change in the intervening years? The above puts a drop shadow around the tabBarItems in the tab bar instead of a shadow above the tab bar itself.

Comment: Same issue as @DanielT. on iOS 17+ - in case anyone has found any solution, please share here.

Answer (score 15):

**For Swift 5 :**

```
tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2
tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
```

Answer (score 12):

Swift 4:

```
tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2
tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer to use a dedicated tab bar methods.

```
// Set `backgroundImage` to be able to use `shadowImage`
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBar.appearance()

if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()

    appearance.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "tab_shadow")
    tabBarAppearance.standardAppearance = appearance
    tabBarAppearance.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
} else {
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(.white)
    tabBarAppearance.shadowImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tab_bar_shadow") // 2x34pt works for me
}
```

Comment: But how did you get the "tab_shadow" image from the shadow parameters?

Comment: @MrKew this is my custom image, semi-transparent pixels

Comment: Yeah, but I have the only the shadow parameters like offset, blur, color, ... But I solved it by creating an UIImage from the shadow using UIGraphicsImageRenderer

Answer (score 3):

> **Swift 4:**

**Use This Extension**

```
extension UIImage {
class func colorForNavBar(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    //let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context!.fill(rect)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


     return image!
    } 
}
```

**Set Shadow Color Using RGB**

```
//Set BackgroundColor
 UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(color: .white)

//Set Shadow Color
 UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(color: UIColor.init(red: 120/255.0, green: 120/255.0, blue: 120/255.0, alpha: 1.0))
```

Comment: Please explain `colorForNavBar ` method.

Comment: @AlexeySavchenko extension Added...!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This one

```
 [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentShadow.png"]];
```

Comment: without the image, this comment is useless.