# Remove UITabBar line not working

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitabbar, shadow

I would like to remove the separator of UITabBar. I have set custom background image for UITabBar. With the following code the separator is above UITabBar image.

```
class myTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
                UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "secretTab.png")

}
```

[image]

I have added following code but it removed not only line but also custom image.(shadow)

```
    class myTabBarController: UITabBarController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.autoresizesSubviews = false
            UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "secretTab.png")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove UITabbar upper border line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645674/remove-uitabbar-upper-border-line)

Comment: @ nathan I have already saw that post. It did not help me :/

Comment: How come ? Was the line removed ? There are quite a lot of answers for this issue in SO: https://google.com/search?hl=en&q=UITabBar%20remove%20hairline+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: I tried "barStyle" "borderWidth" and other things too, it just didnt work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338288/ios-getting-desired-shadow-above-uitabbar

Comment: I wrote the code and shadow is shown but the line is not removed. and if i try to remove line using "self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true", it removed shadow too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certainly looks like a bug. Prior to iOS 10, it worked fine: set a `.backgroundImage` and then set `UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil` (or empty image or transparent image).

With iOS 10, however...

***IF*** your background image is taller than the tab bar, the "shadow image" gets placed at the top of the background image; is 0.5-pts tall, and it *will* be visible.

IF your background image is ***NOT*** taller than the tab bar, the "shadow image" is no longer visible.

And... if you compare the structures between iOS 9 and 10 via Debug Hierarchy, you can see the "shadow image" is a subview of a different view.

So... you *can* get rid of it, but with caveats...

A. use a background image shorter than the tab bar.

B. clip to bounds (but then you lose the top of your background image).

C. use a fully-transparent background... set both `.backgroundImage` and `.shadowImage` to nil or `UIImage()`. Of course, then you need to find some other way to display the image you want as the background of the tab bar.

or... but not recommended...

D. on `viewDidAppear`, step through the tabBar subviews, find the "shadow image", and hide it. This will work - but it could fail if / when Apple changes the structure of the tab bar (and, I suppose, is technically "non-documented", so...):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var b = false
    for v in tabBar.subviews {
        for sv in v.subviews {
            if sv.frame.size.height == 0.5 && sv is UIImageView {
                // found it
                b = true
                sv.isHidden = true
                break
            }
        }
        if b { break }
    }

}
```

Comment: I solved it by changing the height of tabbar and removing the line. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tabBar.shadowImage = nil
        var isFound = false
        for allViews in tabBar.subviews {
            for backgroundViews in allViews.subviews {
                if(backgroundViews is UIImageView)
                {
                    let imageView = backgroundViews as! UIImageView
                    if imageView.image == nil {
                        // found it
                        isFound = true
                        imageView.isHidden = true
                        break
                    }
                }

            }
            if isFound { break }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
  UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Here is apple guideline for [shadowImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623452-shadowimage).

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open var shadowImage: UIImage?
```

> Default is nil. When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of
>   the default shadow image. For a custom shadow to be shown, a custom
>   background image must also be set with -setBackgroundImage: (if the
>   default background image is used, the default shadow image will be
>   used).

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar problem by adjusting the background image height to 49pt.